# Issue in free hand drawing ?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I used below code for free hand drawing on the whole view:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Now my requirement is something like this .. I should be able to draw on particular area of a view. So I modified the code like this ..

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(300, 100));
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 100)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

but the drawing is not proper. Please suggest me how to do this.

Comment: You can try the following link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create custome view like :

> UIView *drawingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y,
>   300, 300)];
>
> [self.view addSubView:drawingView];

And Then modify your code something like below :

> > UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawingView.frame.size);
> >      [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawingView.frame.size.width, drawingView.frame.size.height)];
>
> ```
> CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
> CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
> CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
> CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
> CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
> CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
> CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
> drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
> UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
> ```