# adjust size of drawing view paint example of apple

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uiimageview, drawing

Im Trying to adjust apple example of paint app (using touch) to use scaled view instead of view on the full screen,
No matter what I try when I scale the image to a different size the line is not drawing at the correct place,
the upper i swipe my finger the lower it draws.

for example, if I try to draw in the lower half of the view It works good and drawing the line where the finger touch, if I try to draw in the upper half of the view its drawing the line below where my finger touched.

anyone can point what should I change to make the code work properly ?

If I change the code below to 1004 instead of 500 everything works fine)

the code I use is:

```
//CLASS IMPLEMENTATIONS:
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
drawImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
drawImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 350, 768, 500);
drawImage.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:drawImage];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
mouseMoved = 0;
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

mouseSwiped = NO;
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
    drawImage.image = nil;

    return;
}

lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
lastPoint.y -= 20;

}


- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
mouseSwiped = YES;

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
currentPoint.y -= 20;


UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

lastPoint = currentPoint;

mouseMoved++;

if (mouseMoved == 10) {
    mouseMoved = 0;
}

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
    drawImage.image = nil;
    return;
}


if(!mouseSwiped) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 350, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
}
```

Comment: i think if you use frame drawImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024); then may its works fine hope this help you :)....but its work if it used in iPad

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789989/issue-in-free-hand-drawing

Comment: Hanon thanks but I already tried that and it made things worse, if I use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawingView.frame.size) it always draw at the wrong place.   Paras Joshi , I know it works on full view try to reduce the size not to be 1024 but to be smaller only part of the screen